# React Native: Implementing Custom Background Screen with FLAG_SECURE on Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, security

I'm working on a React Native project where I need to hide the content of my app from the Android "Overview Screen" when it goes into the background. I've tried using the following code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
);
```

This successfully hides the content, but now I want to show a custom screen instead of the default white screen.

Here's the code I've implemented in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private LinearLayout secureLayout;

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "AwesomeProject";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE
        );

        setContentView(R.layout.secure_layout);
        secureLayout = findViewById(R.id.secureLayout); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        secureLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onStart();   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        mainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        secureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
            this,
            getMainComponentName(),
            DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled()
        );
    }
}
```

However, this code is not giving the expected results. The custom screen is not showing up as intended. Can anyone please help me identify where I've gone wrong or suggest a better approach to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your Main Layout an id (like `mainLayout`)
2. Create your custom screen (.xml) to show when app in background. Set an id for it (like `secureLayout`)
3. Add this code to your activity:

```java
LinearLayout mainLayout, secureLayout;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    secureLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    secureLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: where we should initialize   private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private LinearLayout secureLayout;